# Getting Raspberry pi hq camera to work

Tags: 22.04, raspberrypi, camera

I have a Raspberry pi 4 Model B with ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS. Is it possible to work with the raspberry pi hq camera V1.0 2018?

I just found some tutorials for older versions of ubuntu but nothing for ubuntu 22.04. Some advice would help me a lot.